# How to use calc with image in a lightbox gallery

Tags: lightbox, calc

how to use calc function in a gallery with a lightbox with two types of image diferentes de imagens.I try to use calc with a image and din`t work.
I use calc(50vw - 400px) with max width and height.

Comment: Please consider to add more detail. How did you try to use calc?